# Angular scope of ng-if inside Custom Directive's template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ng-if

I've written a custom directive to display either

1) Label text (or)

2) Input (or)

3) Textarea

based on the mode value.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>{{obj}}</h1>
    <div>
        <textbox ng-model='obj.firstName' rows="2"></textbox>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.obj = {};
        $scope.tMode = 'edit';
    });
    app.directive('textbox', function(){
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope:{
                rows : '@',
                ngModel : '='
            },
            template:
                "<h4>{{ngModel}}</h4>" + 
                "<label ng-if=\"$parent.tMode == 'view'\" ng-bind='ngModel'></label>" + 
                "<input ng-if=\"$parent.tMode == 'edit' && (!rows || rows <= 1)\"  type='text' class='form-control' ng-model='ngModel'>" +
                "<textarea ng-if=\"$parent.tMode == 'edit' && rows && rows > 1\" rows='rows' class='form-control' ng-model='ngModel'></textarea>"
        }
    });
</script>
```

Since the conditions were declared in `ng-if` instead of `ng-show \ ng-hide` inside directive template, I can't able to display `<h4>{{ngModel}}</h4>` because `ng-if` creates a child scope for the `input / textarea` fields.

I know that the model values can be accessed if declared as `ng-model="$parent.ngModel"` in the template.

But is it okay if it's declared as `ng-model="$parent.ngModel"`..? I think it's somewhat not straight forward way to do it. Is there any alternative approaches to tackle this..? (other than using `ng-show / ng-hide`)

Comment: Can you please prepare a Fiddle ?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems with displaying `<h4>{{ngModel}}</h4>`. It just displays parent ngModel... there isn't any `ng-if` that would hide it.